# HTML2PDF not working in linux after Upgrade PDFNet to 9.3.8 and HTML2PDF.so version 1.0.0.4

Tags: html2pdf, pdftron

PDFNET  SDK 8.1.17 and HTML2PDF 1.0.0.4 ,everything works

PDFNET SDK 9.3.8 and HTML2PDF 1.0.0.4 , Not working.

Looks like new library may be not converting html to pdf in given temp path from PDFNET SDK
PDFNet.setTempPath(tempPDFTron.toString());
PDFNet.setPersistentCachePath(tempPDFTron.toString());

or need some additional configuration in the code for Linux. On Windows, everything works with old and new library setup.
We are using CentOS 6 and GLIBC version is 2.12. (New PDFNET SDK works fine for other conversions with this setup) only HTML2PDF conversion is failing.

We tried to execute pdftron sample on same linux environment and getting same exception as below.

```
2 Conversion failed. HTTP Code: 0
Missing output file /tmp/pdftron/Trn-13950-1663686283-c7569d55-eecc-4e39-a897-585d3edfa2d1
-Permission: write
```

**Note: We cannot upgrade latest html2pdf because of GLIBC 2.12**

Comment: What happens if you call "./html2pdf.so" from the command line? What about "./html2pdf.so url out.pdf" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with PDFNet 9.2 there is a new HTML2PDF module, and PDFNet relies now on the *name* of the module to know which interface to work.

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/linux/changelog/9-2-0/#updated-html-to-pdf-module

Please make sure that the folder you pass to `HTML2PDF.SetModulePath` contains only `html2pdf.so` file.

Comment: yes, we was setting path with filename in setModulePath, but after removing file from modulePath it start working. Thanks